# What application is needed to find an email host

Tags: command-line

What application do I need to find an email host? I have used mx lookup and was wondering what the linux version was called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dig` command from `dnsutils` package, if it's not installed then install it using:

```
sudo apt install dnsutils:
```

And to use it:

```
dig -t mx hostname.com
```

For example:

```
$ dig -t mx gmail.com  +short

20 alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
40 alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
10 alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
5 gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
30 alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
```

Comment: thank you!                     Warning, ignoring invalid type max  <  what does that indicate

Comment: Use `mx` not `max`